# Multiplying checkbox item in a group to relative number field

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, multiplication

I have a code that multiplies checkbox item to a number field when selected. When there's multiple items in one checkbox array it only multiplies the first. How i do i separate the checkbox group? should a create a unique name and script for each item?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ayco7hr/) Here

Here's my HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="1" value="30" name="1" />
<div style="display:none;" class="checked-1">
    <input type="number" name="product_1_qty[]" id="product_1_qty" placeholder="Quantity" class=" qty" value="0" />
</div>


<p>Total: PHP <span id='total'>0</span></p>
```

and here's the script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    var qty = 0;

    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
        if ($('.1').is(':checked')) {
            $('.checked-1').show(); 
        } else {
            $('.checked-1').hide();
        }
    });
     $('.qty').bind('keyup mouseup', function () { // if user typed anyting in the Quantity
          sum = parseInt($('.1').val()); // get checkbox value and change the data type to int
          qty = parseInt($(this).val()); // get Quantity value and change the data type to int
          //console.log(sum,qty);
          if(sum && qty) { // if the values was not empty
              $('#total').text(sum * qty); // show the result in the total element
          } else { // if the values was empty
              $('#total').val(''); // clear the result textbox
          }
     });
});
```

I wanted to have have multiple items inside one checkbox array

```
<input type="checkbox" class="1" value="30" name="1" />
<div style="display:none;" class="checked-1">
    <input type="number" name="product_1_qty[]" id="product_1_qty" placeholder="Quantity" class=" qty" value="0" />
</div>


<p>Total: PHP <span id='total'>0</span></p>

<input type="checkbox" class="1" value="30" name="1" />
<div style="display:none;" class="checked-1">
    <input type="number" name="product_1_qty[]" id="product_1_qty" placeholder="Quantity" class=" qty" value="0" />
</div>


<p>Total: PHP <span id='total'>0</span></p>

<input type="checkbox" class="1" value="30" name="1" />
<div style="display:none;" class="checked-1">
    <input type="number" name="product_1_qty[]" id="product_1_qty" placeholder="Quantity" class=" qty" value="0" />
</div>


<p>Total: PHP <span id='total'>0</span></p>
```

And when I do that, the code goes awry.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: your JS Fiddle link is broken.

Comment: @Keeleon there fixed it. thanks for the heads up

Comment: @Blazemonger i was planning to make the ID dynamic ( id="<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>"  ) so if use that, how can I incorporate it in the script?

Comment: That's a separate problem. You'd have to keep track of which IDs you've used somehow. Or just use classes.

Comment: @Blazemonger I understand. If I use classes, would it be possible to reference to it in the script individually for each checkbox item in the array? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be repeating the same block of HTML, you should use classes instead of IDs (since IDs need to be unique) and then use [jQuery's tree traversal methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) to find the correct form elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  var qty = 0;

  $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).next('.checked-1').show();
    } else {
      $(this).next('.checked-1').hide();
    }
  });
  $('.qty').bind('keyup mouseup', function() { // if user typed anyting in the Quantity
    sum = parseInt($(this).parent().prev('.1').val()); // get checkbox value and change the data type to int
    qty = parseInt($(this).val()); // get Quantity value and change the data type to int
    //console.log(sum,qty);
    if (sum && qty) { // if the values was not empty
      $(this).parent().next('p').find('.total').text(sum * qty); // show the result in the total element
    } else { // if the values was empty
      $(this).parent().next('p').find('.total').val(''); // clear the result textbox
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<input type="checkbox" class="1" value="30" name="1" />
<div style="display:none;" class="checked-1">
  <input type="number" name="product_1_qty[]" id="" placeholder="Quantity" class=" qty" value="0" />
</div>
<p>Total: PHP <span class='total'>0</span>
</p>



<input type="checkbox" class="1" value="30" name="1" />
<div style="display:none;" class="checked-1">
  <input type="number" name="product_1_qty[]" id="" placeholder="Quantity" class=" qty" value="0" />
</div>
<p>Total: PHP <span class='total'>0</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you! much appreciated

Comment: so logically the Tree Traversal is like a loop for jquery? Apologies, jquery illiterate

Comment: No, tree traversal methods (like `.next()`, `.prev()`, `.parent()` and `.find()`) are for moving up and down the DOM tree. They let you specify which DOM elements you want relative to the one you're at. If you change your HTML significantly, you'll need to update your code to find the desired DOM elements again.

Comment: I see. Great insight. Thanks again